# How can i take only the true property from a class

Tags: c#

I have a class with 6 property:

```
public class ControllerValuesArgs:EventArgs
    {
        // debouncer for button
        private static int btnCounter = 0;
        // flag to send buttons
        bool activeFlag = false;

        /// <summary>
        /// Default constructor.
        /// </summary>
        public ControllerValuesArgs()
        {
            // Reset buttons to initial state
            ResetButtons();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets state of button 1.
        /// </summary>
        public bool Button1Pressed
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets state of button 2.
        /// </summary>
        public bool Button2Pressed
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets state of button 3.
        /// </summary>
        public bool Button3Pressed
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets state of button 4.
        /// </summary>
        public bool Button4Pressed
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets state of button 5.
        /// </summary>
        public bool Button5Pressed
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets state of button 6.
        /// </summary>
        public bool Button6Pressed
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
```

I want to use the the property with true result inside to put it in a hashtable and converted to string.
What i try:

```
 /// <summary>
        /// Handler listening on Conontroller variables needed to calculate the expression.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">The source of the event.</param>
        /// <param name="e">An object that contains no event data.</param>
        public void ConontrollerValuesUpdate(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ControllerValuesArgs conontrollerValuesArgs = new ControllerValuesArgs();

            hashtable["UserInput"] = conontrollerValuesArgs.ToString();
            CalculateExpression();
        }
```

**How can i call ore search for the true result in all property from that class and put it in the table?**

Comment: Always when you ask yourself such things, use a collection instead. For example a `bool[] ButtonsPressed`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is similar to converting any object to ExpandoObject as ExpandObject implements IDictionary<string,object>.

This should give you dictionary with properties.

```
public static class DynamicExtensions
{
   public static IDictionary<string, object> ToDynamicDictionary(this object value)
    {
        IDictionary<string, object> expando = new ExpandoObject();

        foreach (PropertyDescriptor property in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(value.GetType()))
            expando.Add(property.Name, property.GetValue(value));

        return expando;
    }
}
```

Answer based on http://blog.jorgef.net/2011/06/converting-any-object-to-dynamic.html

Comment: now how can I get out only the button with the true flag form 'expando'?

Comment: You'll have to iterate through all dictionary items and check items that have the Key that matches your name criteria and Value == true. This is elementary programming skill.